# Is there a way to retain textfield value after submitting without using ajax of session?

Tags: php, html

Good day,

I have a project here which has an inline-editing.
It means that I have a populated table, and inside the table is a 
textfield and a button each row.

What I am trying to achieve is after editing a row, i.e. row 1 and saving it,
the row 2 that I also edited value will not be removed or changed... and without
using an ajax and session.

**[Update]**

We decided to use Ajax, it is now running correctly,
But we encountered another problem.

I.e. i have 3 rows,
row 1 : I edited the values in the textfield (the value needs to be retained after submitting). but not yet saved.
row 2 : row 2 is deleted, and the result should reflect immediately.

Problem.
After using Ajax, the field is retained after submitting (correct)
But the table, after deleteion, is not reflected immediately.

Question :
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so you can achieve this. Because ajax is the way to make working you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, ajax is the way to go.

If you are forced not to use it, I can think of a way how to achieve the desired results - save the *entire* table, not only the row. But that's an abominable monster of a solution, especially if you could use a clean ajax or session with little to no consequences for performance...